# Spring XD - instanceof in SpEL expression in filter

Tags: spring-xd

I'm trying to use the instanceof operator in a SpEL expression in a filter for a stream.  I'm trying the following:

```
stream create myStream --definition "tap:job:jobName > filter --expression='payload instanceof T(com.package.name.event.SomeEvent)' | log --deploy
```

I am publishing my own event to the xd.job.aggregatedEvents channel.  My intention is to log only my SomeEvent's by filtering using the instanceof operator.

The problem is I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1005E:(pos 0): Type cannot be found 'com.package.name.event.SomeEvent'
```

My question is can anyone advise me as to the proper syntax for instanceof in SpEL expressions? Or if this is correct syntax then what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the StackStrace - `Type cannot be found` and the logic from the `StandardTypeLocator`:

```
try {
    return ClassUtils.forName(nameToLookup, this.classLoader);
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException ey) {
    // try any registered prefixes before giving up
....
throw new SpelEvaluationException(SpelMessage.TYPE_NOT_FOUND, typeName);
```

You just end up with the issue like `ClassNotFoundException`. So, your jar with the `com.package.name.event.SomeEvent` is outside of the XD CLASSPATH.

You can compare it using literal:

```
--expression='payload.class.name == '''com.package.name.event.SomeEvent''''
```

Or just place your jar to the `dirt container` classpath.

From other side it is always a bad idea to use domain-specific types for messaging systems. You should think how to overcome that using standard supported types and replace the check condition to some value (in the standard type) to the message headers.

Comment: Thanks Artem. I ended up following your advice and making the message a String and adding a header which I use to filter. So the stream now looks like: stream create myStream --definition "tap:job:jobName > filter --expression='headers[\"custom_event\"] != null' | log --deploy